# How to properly format unusual date string using Java SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, matcher

I've got date in following format:

```
Pon Cze 07, 2011 9:42 pm
```

It's Polish equivalent of English date:

```
Mon Jun 07, 2011 9:42 pm
```

I'm using following SimpleDateFormat matcher:

```
SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy H:mm a", new Locale("pl", "PL"))
```

But date cannot be parsed because of AssertionFailedError. I've try some other solution, but no one works for me. Do you got any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried JodaTime? - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: JodaTime is slighter slow then SimpleDateFormat because it invoke SimpleDateFormat to parse date. Performance in this project is most important so I stay on SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: **I've resolved my problem - I've used DateFormatSymbols setShortWeekdays method and I've changed "H" to lowercase. The date now parse correctly.** Now I can't answer to my question, because of Stackoveflow restriction for new users, but after next 7 hours i paste code as an answer.

Comment: Please post your answer

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

1. The day is `wt`, and not `Pon`, in the pl locale
2. The AM/PM indicator is not taken into account because you used `H` (which means hour from 0 to 23) instead of `h`.

I would just parse from the first character after the first white space (to avoid parsing "Pon"), adn replace `H` by `h`. in the pattern:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a", new Locale("pl", "PL"));
Date d = df.parse(s.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the day of the week is only represented by two Letters, whatever the reason for this might be.
Try this Code and check the Output

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy H:mm a", new Locale("pl", "PL"));
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(new Locale("pl", "PL"));
    gc.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(gc.getTime()));
```

My Output is: "Wt wrz 27, 2011 11:05 AM"

So maybe if you try two lettered weekdays, it could work